# If a point circle is placed on another circle, how much intersections do they have?

Tags: geometry, circles

*Backstory: I am currently making a program, that takes in position and radius of two circles, and outputs if they intersect at $0$, $1$, $2$, or $∞$ points. I have just found this edge case, and am not sure what to output for it.*

Say, we have a circle with its center on $(0,0)$ and a radius of $3$, and the point circle, a circle with a radius of $0$, with it's center on $(0,3)$. The question is, how much intersection points do the two circles have?

Comment: There is only one point of intersection, namely (0,3), since the "point circle" possesses this only point and shares it with the first circle at the same time.

Comment: @Abezhiko why didn't you answer the question, but put the answer in a comment instead?

Comment: There are many reasons that people do this. But a common one is out of deference to a big rule on MSE: that questioners should not edit their Question in a way that would invalidate existing Answers. So if someone has answered the question as literally posed, but is concerned that it was not the *intended* question, it's polite to put it in a comment so that the questioner can edit a fix. I won't claim to be inside Abezhiko's head, but personally I would have this concern here: why would you have doubts that a point on a circle intersects the circle in one point?

Comment: It depends upon your overall context and intention. ... Consider, for instance, two *tangent* circles. Geometrically, they have a single point in common; algebraically, it's usually helps to say that there's a "double-point" of intersection. For your point-circle: geometrically, there is just the one point at issue; algebraically, there's a case for a double-point. An argument for $\infty$ might be a bit forced. ... Generally, degenerate figures are difficult to discuss in isolation. They tend to make more sense as "limiting cases" of families of non-degenerate figures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the name of God
Well, You can say a circle with radius 0, has only one point located on its perimeter, which is its center. To understand why this happens, notice circle's equation :
$r ^2 = (x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2$ where circle is (h,k).
 If r  = 0, the only solution to the equation is x = h and y = k . As a result, in this case, there is one point of intersection.